# Add additional check to WHERE statement

Tags: sql

Can I add additional check to `WHERE` statement if some bool check is true. Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE (CASE WHEN ID = 1 THEN EmployeeName = @Name)
```

I know that this example does not work but I just want to show what I want to do.

Comment: Skip the case, use AND/OR instead.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're trying to do there.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Please add some sample input and output data, to clarify the problem. And describe the issue using words, not (failing) code

Comment: Are you trying to make different bool comparisions depending on different values of ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can emulate this behavior with logical operators:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Employee 
WHERE  id <> 1 OR EmployeeName = @Name
```

Comment: In this case if first false second will not be checked. Is that true?

Comment: @mojo It depends on the implementation of the [tag:rdbms] you're using, but any half decent database (and any database I've ever had experience with) should short circuit the evaluation - so, in a word, yes.

Comment: `!=` is product specific not equals operator. ANSI/ISO SQL has `<>` instead. (No dbms tagged...)

Comment: @jarlh `!=` is so commonly supported that I forgot it's not ANSI. Good point though! I've edited my answer to use the standard ANSI operator.

Comment: Yes, I guess most dbms products support it. (I used it for years, and comma separated tables instead of explicit joins as well...)